# write a generic method to print out the element of listoflist using stream in java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am new to Java Generics. I have two List with different type **Object** and **Integer** and i want to write a generic  method which takes the list of lists and want to print out the containing elements inside the list. Example

```
  List<Object> list1 = List.of(1, List.of(2, 3, 4, List.of(5)), List.of(6, 7));
    genericmethod(list1);
    System.out.println();
  
    List<Integer> list2 = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    genericmethod(list2);
    System.out.println();
    both the method should print 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

    I tried with

     public static void genericmethod(List<?> list) { 
         list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
     }
```

Output :
1
[2, 3, 4, [5]]
[6, 7]

and

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

But i want to print out just 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 from both the list as a result.

Comment: Please explain what is your use cases. Why do you need such a complex structure with nested lists?

Comment: It was one of my University question. I solved by doing                                                                                               public static void genericmethod(List<?> list) { List<?> 

        list.stream().forEach(elem -> {
            if (elem instanceof Collection) {
                genericmethod((List<?>) elem);
            } else {
                System.out.println(elem);
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 2):

In decades of Java development, I've never found a case where this sort of structure was the right approach. I'd suggest finding a type-safe way to store your data, perhaps using a simple custom type.

You can't do this in a type-safe way, as the common ancestor of `List` and `Integer` is `Object`. You have to test the type dynamically and act accordingly:

```java
static Stream<Object> expand(Collection<?> elements) {
  return elements.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e instanceof Collection col ? col.stream() : Stream.of(e));
}
```

Your example would use such a function like this:

```java
expand(list1).forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println();
expand(list2).forEach(System.out::print);
System.out.println();
```

If you know that all the "leaf" elements of your input are a specific type—say, `Integer`—you can perform type checking at runtime and write a generic method:

```java
static <T> Stream<T> expand(Class<? extends T> t, Collection<?> elements) {
  return elements.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e instanceof Collection col ? col.stream() : Stream.of(t.cast(e)));
}

int total = expand(Integer.class, list1).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

Perhaps the lists can be nested to any depth:

```java
static <T> Stream<T> expand(Class<? extends T> t, Collection<?> elements) {
  return elements.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e instanceof Collection col ? expand(t, col) : Stream.of(t.cast(e)));
}
```